# Custom Logarithm Lua (Answer has trick that can be used on almost any language)

Tags: math, lua, logarithm

I'm working on a base converter for lua that can convert the base of any number to another base. For that, I need a logarithm calculator. Example function (where `logarithm(100, 10)` would equal log<sub>10</sub>(100), which would equal 2):

```
function logarithm(value, base)
    ... -- Algorithm here
end
print(logarithm(100, 10))
```

Which would output:

```
2
```

P.S: I want the algorithm to accept any base, any value.

Comment: Furthermore, if you have access to Lua 5.2, the [`math.log`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.log "Returns the logarithm of x in the given base. The default for base is e (so that the function returns the natural logarithm of x).") function has an optional `base` argument.

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always use that

> log<sub>b</sub>(a) = log<sub>c</sub>(a) / log<sub>c</sub>(b)

where `c` is one of the provided bases, like the Euler number `e` of the natural logarithm or 10, sometimes also the basis 2 logarithm is provided.

Comment: Thanks, this trick could also be used on just about any language that has a `log10` function.

Comment: It works for any `c`, not just 10 or the Euler constant.

Answer (score 0):

for example math.log2 can be done as

```
math.log2 = function (x)
    return math.log(x) / math.log(2)
end
```